# Привязанное свойство зависимости не изменяется

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Привет всем. Не могу разобраться в `DependencyProperty`. Допустим у нас есть UserControl - LoginBox. Внутри этого контрола лежит TextBox, у которого свойство Text подвязано на свойство Text, которое в свою очередь объявлено в codebehind внутри LoginBox:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PTRCPriceCalculator.LoginBox"
             x:Name="UC" ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=Text}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Свойство Text, объявленное в LoginBox:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Text",
    typeof( string ),
    typeof( LoginBox ) );

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue( TextProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( TextProperty, value ); }
    }
```

Так вот, как Вы видите, я подписал обработчик на TextChanged внутреннего контрола TextBox:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var p = Text;   // Здесь всегда null. Почему?
}
```

Как Вы поняли, Text - объявленное мною свойство зависимости, всегда равно null, когда я изменяю текст в TextBox. Почему так? Ведь я его привязал к свойству Text моего TextBox'а, почему оно не изменяется?

Я пробовал и вот так `Text="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"` привязывать - бестолку. Свойство Text все равно null.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: А где а вы сделали привязку к `DataContext`?

Comment: А вы не забыли UpdateSourceTrigger?

Comment: @VladD Забыл. Уже исправил. Все работает. Спасибо:)

Comment: @Bretbas: Тогда напишите ответ, чтобы вопрос не был без ответа.

Comment: @VladD, в указанном мной дубликате задача один в один. Смысла от нового ответа мало. Лучше закрыть как дубликат

Comment: @Андрей: Да, вы правы, так и сделал.